# How to supress any title or caption for \lstinputlisting?

Tags: latex, listings

I am using

```
\lstinputlisting[]{javacode/DatabaseManager-getUser}
```

to show some java code. However the following caption appears underneath the listing (see picture marked with red arrow):

[image: Listing with caption]

In my preamble I have used `\lstset` to set `title={}`, however I don't want anything there, no title or caption. Is this possible? And if so how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Hi! Please provide a minimal working example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))! Otherwise, if I compile `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{listings}\begin{document}\lstinputlisting[]{so.out}\end{document}`, this produces no caption "Listing:". Also, check page 18 of the [package guide](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf): _If you don’t want the label Listing plus number, you should use title [...]_.

Comment: Hi im sorry about the missing MWE, I refrained from it, since my document size was really big, but your comment made me double check my preamble and I found the issue and fixed it so thanks. :D I will post the answer so others might get use out of it. :)

Answer (score 1):

See MattAllegros comment in OP. It made me find the issue. In my preamble I had the following setup:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{grayC},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  breakatwhitespace=false,        
  breaklines=true,             
  captionpos=b,                 
  commentstyle=\color{greencomments},   
  deletekeywords={...},    
  escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
  extendedchars=true,            
  frame=single,                   
  keepspaces=true,                
  keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords},       
  language=Java,              
  morekeywords={partial, var, value, get, set},           
  numbers=left,                  
  numbersep=5pt,                   
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{black}, 
  rulecolor=\color{Dgray},         
  showspaces=false,               
  showstringspaces=false,         
  showtabs=false,                  
  stepnumber=1,                    
  stringstyle=\color{redstrings},  
  tabsize=2,                      
  morekeywords= {new, std::*,},                
  title={}                         
}
```

I commented out `captionpos=b` and `title={}`, and now I get nothing underneath the listing as was what I wanted in OP. for output comparrison see:

[image: Listing without caption or title]